# reading excel file and saving to database?

Tags: oracle, excel, servlets, vector, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel file and saving it to database.

I am iterating each row and cell and saving it to vector object, and then using loops, saving it to database. While I am saving it database, I am doing this:

```
id = ((XSSFCell) cellStoreVector.get(0)).toString()==null?"":((XSSFCell) cellStoreVector.get(0)).toString();
```

for every column. Everything else fine except for this one where I am getting 2.01356229E8 as id. I don't know why I am getting 2.01356229E8 in my id..is should be like this 201356229.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you turning your numbers into strings before writing them to the database? Shouldn't you be storing them as a number instead?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an Excel display problem, because the value has already been extracted into Java with Apache POI.  But when `XSSFCell#toString()` is called, the Apache POI code uses the following expression to convert a cell with type `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` to a string in `toString()`:

```
return getNumericCellValue() + "";
```

The [`XSSFCell#getNumericCellValue()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue%28%29) method returns a `double`, which when converted to a string yields the string `"2.01356229E8"`.  This is the expected Java conversion from a `double` to a `String` because `"2.01356229E8"` is the scientific notation representation for `201356229`.  (In math, the representations `201356229` and `2.01356229E8` are equivalent.)

If the column in the Oracle database that you're saving to is a `VARCHAR2`, then you'll need to format the String value before saving it to the database.  This will store `"201356229"` in `id`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
id = df.format( ((XSSFCell) cellStoreVector.get(0)).getNumericCellValue() );
```

If the column is a `NUMBER`, then don't bother converting it to a String first, just use the numeric cell value as a `double` to pass on to the database.

```
double numericId = ((XSSFCell) cellStoreVector.get(0)).getNumericCellValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an Excel display problem. Excel doesn't know that you want this to be an integer.

You might want to make this wider (select the whole column, right click, Column width... and enter 10).

You might also select the column, right-click, Format cells..., select Number, change Decimal places to 0).